# Batch file find syntax error - not sure what I did wrong

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find, compare

I'm trying to compare two files for change using .cmd. Now, I only need to find a small string to compare rather than the whole files.

The information is immediately after "change number : " in these files. As follows:

```
Steam Console Client (c) Valve Corporation
-- type 'quit' to exit --
Loading Steam API...OK.
AppID : 346110, change number : 1230200/1230201, token 0, last change : Wed Aug 19 08:36:34 2015 
"346110"
```

In this case the result should be "1230200/1230201"

Here is the code I am trying to use.

```
rem Because its SteamCMD we only want to check change numbers as other parts of the file change frequently
for /f "tokens=3 delims=:/" %%a in ('find "change number :" ^< %~n0-latest-version ') do SET "latest=%%a"
for /f "tokens=3 delims=:/" %%a in ('find "change number :" ^< %~n0-current-version ') do SET "current=%%a"
IF NOT %latest% == %current% goto shutdown_server
```

When the `IF NOT %latest% == %current%` line is ran there isn't any information stored in %latest% and %current%.

I believe I have some sort of syntax error in my code but I just don't see it. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the output of `find "change number :" < %~n0-latest-version` and `find "change number :" < %~n0-current-version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second number will not be picked up with the first number if '/' is specified as a delimiter. This is -very- hardcoded.

```
C:>type f-current-version
team API...OK.
AppID : 346110, change number : 1230200/1230201, token 0, last change : Wed Aug 19 08:36:34 2015
"346110"

C:>type f-latest-version
team API...OK.
AppID : 346110, change number : 1230200/1230201, token 0, last change : Wed Aug 19 08:36:34 2015
"346110"
```

The cmd script

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims=:, " %%a in ('find "change number :" ^< %~n0-latest-version ') do SET "latest=%%a"
for /f "tokens=5 delims=:, " %%a in ('find "change number :" ^< %~n0-current-version ') do SET "current=%%a"

echo %latest%
echo %current%

C:>f.bat
1230200/1230201
1230200/1230201
```

Comment: I feel foolish. That fixed my issue. Thank you.